# How to draw a line from vertex to vertex using Graphics Class?

Tags: java, class, graphics

I am trying to draw a line from each node graphics object to another node graphics object if and only if there exists an edge between the two nodes.

My graph is implemented inside a 2-dimensional boolean adjacency matrix.

How would I implement this?

Here is what I have so far:

```
// Draw method which will draw the shape of the graph.
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        //Define parameters to draw the graph in. Example taken from
        //http://www.zetcode.com/gfx/java2d/basicdrawing/
        Dimension size = getSize();
        Insets insets = getInsets();

        int w = size.width - insets.left - insets.right;
        int h = size.height - insets.top - insets.bottom;

        //Parameters for vertices, to be used later to draw vertices.
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        // Extend to Graphics 2D
        Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D) g;

        // Set preferences. This cleans up edges.
        graph.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        //Generate vertices as random points on JPanel.
        Random r = new Random();

        //Draw random points on JPanel for the vertices.
        for (int l = 0; l < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; l++){
            String str = Integer.toHexString(l);
            //Define where a specific vertex will fall on a x, y coordinate
            //inside the container.
            x = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % w;
            y = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % h;
            //Initialize a node graphics object to represent vertices.
            Graphics2D node = (Graphics2D)g;
            node.fillOval(x, y, 7, 7); //Creates filled ovals for nodes.
            graph.drawString(str, x, y + 20);
        }

            //Create a nexted for loop to see if there is an edge between vertices.
        for (int m = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; m++){
            for (int n = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges[m].length; m++){
                if (adj_Matrix_Edges[m][n]){
                    graph.drawLine(node, y1, x2, y2);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Start by calling `super.paint`, in fact, you should avoid overriding `paint` at all an instead use `paintComponent` instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As MadProgrammer already mentioned, the drawing process in a class that inherits from `JComponent` is usually done in the `paintComponent` method:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
{
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g;

    // Your drawing stuff goes here....
}
```

But regarding the actual question: I assume that you want to draw a graph (or more precisely: A node-link diagram). There are many, many sophisticated libraries for this task. And for all but the simplest application, I'd **strongly** recommend to use such a library, because doing this manually may become rather tricky.

However, the main problem at the moment is that you are creating new random points each time that the component is repainted! I wonder what this looks like. You should see oddly flickering points when you resize the component.

You'll have to somehow store the points (their coordinates), so that you may draw lines between these points later.

It is possible to do this with very few modifications to your code:

```
//Generate vertices as random points on JPanel.
// Pass "0" as the argument to the constructor of Random, so that it 
// will always create the same sequence of random numbers
Random r = new Random(0);

// Create lists that will store the point coordinates
List<Integer> pointsX = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> pointsY = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int l = 0; l < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; l++){
    String str = Integer.toHexString(l);
    //Define where a specific vertex will fall on a x, y coordinate
    //inside the container.
    x = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % w;
    y = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % h;

    // Store the coordinates of the points:
    pointsX.add(x);
    pointsY.add(y);

    //Initialize a node graphics object to represent vertices.
    Graphics2D node = (Graphics2D)g;
    node.fillOval(x, y, 7, 7); //Creates filled ovals for nodes.
    graph.drawString(str, x, y + 20);
}

//Create a nexted for loop to see if there is an edge between vertices.
for (int m = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; m++){
    for (int n = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges[m].length; m++){
        if (adj_Matrix_Edges[m][n]){

            // Fetch the coordinates of the points from the list
            int xm = pointsX.get(m);
            int ym = pointsY.get(m);
            int xn = pointsX.get(n);
            int yn = pointsY.get(n);
            graph.drawLine(xm,ym,xn,yn);
        }
    }
}
```

But I do **NOT** recommend to do it like this. That's only a quick hack to show how this may be achieved with minimal modifications to your code. In general, you should **NOT** build any data structures while painting. The painting code should be as short and as simple as possible.

Instead, you should create a data structure that represents your nodes when you initialize your adjacency matrix. You could at least create some class like

```
class Node
{
    String name;
    // Coordinates, between 0 and 1
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

And where the `adj_Matrix_Edges` is declared and initialized, you could also create a list of nodes, like this:

```
boolean adj_Matrix_Edges[][];
List<Node> nodes;

void initializeMatrix()
{
    adj_Matrix_Edges = ...;

    // Create the nodes
    Random random = new Random(0);
    nodes= new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (int m = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; m++)
    {
        Node node= new Node();
        node.name = Integer.toHexString(m);
        node.x = random.nextDouble(); 
        node.y = random.nextDouble(); 
        nodes.add(node);
    }
}
```

Later, when you paint, you can access these nodes and paint them direcly:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gr)
{
    super.paintComponent(gr);
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)g;

    for (int l = 0; l < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; l++){

        // Compute the x- and y-coordinates that the
        // node will have in this component. (That's 
        // why the coordinates that are stored in 
        // the "Node" class should always be 
        // between 0 and 1!)

        Node node = nodes.get(l);
        int ix = (int)(node.x * getWidth());
        int iy = (int)(node.y * getHeight());

        g.fillOval(ix, iy, 7, 7);
        graph.drawString(node.name, ix, iy + 20);
    }

    //Create a nested for loop to see if there is an edge between vertices.
    for (int m = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges.length; m++){
        for (int n = 0; m < adj_Matrix_Edges[m].length; m++){
            if (adj_Matrix_Edges[m][n]){

                Node nodeM = nodes.get(m);                    
                Node nodeN = nodes.get(n);
                int xm = (int)(nodeM.x * getWidth());
                int ym = (int)(nodeM.y * getHeight());
                int xn = (int)(nodeN.x * getWidth());
                int yn = (int)(nodeN.y * getHeight());
                graph.drawLine(xm,ym,xn,yn); 
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Usually, you will also have a representation of the *edges* that is similar to the `Node` class that I sketched above, but then you are slowly approaching the complexities that justify to use a library like JUNG http://jung.sourceforge.net/ or JGraphX https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx (There are many graph libraries out there, and these are probably two of the most popular ones, but should only be considered as examples here)

Comment: Marco13 thank you for your long thought out explanation, it helped tremendously. I will do what you say in the future!

EDIT - Actually I will modify my code now and study the concepts you listed now instead of later so I incorporate these habits now.